# TCP model , implementing seq_number

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I use TCP for transmission layer.But may be my payload is bigger than my buffer, So I have to implement seq_number of TCP in my payloads.
 Do you know some class or module or some way to do it?
**UPDATE:**
My packet contains header+payload.

Answer (score 1):

**If you would like to implement the TCP seq_number logic by yourself** theres this github repository called  "***TCP Emulator***":
https://github.com/ohEmily/tcp-emulator-python

**If you want only to create tcp packet header with seq_number** i'de use the ***Python socket module***

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import struct


class TCPPacket:
 def __init__(self, dport = 80, sport = 65535, dst='127.0.0.1', src='192.168.1.101', data = 'Nothing'):
  self.dport = dport
  self.sport = sport
  self.src_ip = src
  self.dst_ip = dst
  self.data   = data
  self.raw = None
  self.create_tcp_feilds()

 def assemble_tcp_feilds(self):
  self.raw = struct.pack('!HHLLBBHHH', # Data Structure Representation
   self.tcp_src,   # Source IP
   self.tcp_dst,    # Destination IP
   self.tcp_seq,    # Sequence
   self.tcp_ack_seq,  # Acknownlegment Sequence
   self.tcp_hdr_len,   # Header Length
   self.tcp_flags ,    # TCP Flags
   self.tcp_wdw,   # TCP Windows
   self.tcp_chksum,  # TCP cheksum
   self.tcp_urg_ptr # TCP Urgent Pointer
   )

  self.calculate_chksum() # Call Calculate CheckSum
  return


 def reassemble_tcp_feilds(self):
  self.raw = struct.pack('!HHLLBBH', 
   self.tcp_src, 
   self.tcp_dst, 
   self.tcp_seq, 
   self.tcp_ack_seq, 
   self.tcp_hdr_len, 
   self.tcp_flags , 
   self.tcp_wdw
   )+
  struct.pack("H", 
   self.tcp_chksum
   )+
  struct.pack('!H', 
   self.tcp_urg_ptr
   )
  return

 def calculate_chksum(self):
  src_addr     = socket.inet_aton( self.src_ip )
  dest_addr    = socket.inet_aton( self.dst_ip )
  placeholder  = 0
  protocol     = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
  tcp_len      = len(self.raw) + len(self.data)

  psh = struct.pack('!4s4sBBH' , 
   src_addr , 
   dest_addr , 
   placeholder , 
   protocol , 
   tcp_len
   )

  psh = psh + self.raw + self.data

  self.tcp_chksum = self.chksum(psh)

  self.reassemble_tcp_feilds()

  return 


 def chksum(self, msg):
  s = 0  # Binary Sum

  # loop taking 2 characters at a time
  for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):

   a = ord(msg[i]) 
   b = ord(msg[i+1])
   s = s + (a+(b << 8))


  # One's Complement
  s = s + (s >> 16)
  s = ~s & 0xffff
  return s

 def create_tcp_feilds(self):

  # ---- [ Source Port ]
  self.tcp_src = self.sport

  # ---- [ Destination Port ]
  self.tcp_dst = self.dport

  # ---- [ TCP Sequence Number]
  self.tcp_seq = 0

  # ---- [ TCP Acknowledgement Number]
  self.tcp_ack_seq = 0

  # ---- [ Header Length ]
  self.tcp_hdr_len = 80

  # ---- [ TCP Flags ]
  tcp_flags_rsv = (0 << 9)
  tcp_flags_noc = (0 << 8)
  tcp_flags_cwr = (0 << 7)
  tcp_flags_ecn = (0 << 6)
  tcp_flags_urg = (0 << 5)
  tcp_flags_ack = (0 << 4)
  tcp_flags_psh = (0 << 3)
  tcp_flags_rst = (0 << 2)
  tcp_flags_syn = (1 << 1)
  tcp_flags_fin = (0)

  self.tcp_flags = tcp_flags_rsv + tcp_flags_noc + tcp_flags_cwr + \
        tcp_flags_ecn + tcp_flags_urg + tcp_flags_ack + \
        tcp_flags_psh + tcp_flags_rst + tcp_flags_syn + tcp_flags_fin

  # ---- [ TCP Window Size ]
  self.tcp_wdw = socket.htons (5840)

  # ---- [ TCP CheckSum ]
  self.tcp_chksum = 0

  # ---- [ TCP Urgent Pointer ]
  self.tcp_urg_ptr = 0


  return
```

In order to run it:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
        # Create Raw Socket
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)

 tcp = TCPPacket()
 tcp.assemble_tcp_feilds()

 s.sendto(tcp.raw, ('127.0.0.1' , 0 ))
```

Source: http://www.bitforestinfo.com/2017/12/code-to-create-tcp-packet-header-with-python-socket-module.html

Comment: Oh, no, I said "I use TCP as transmission layer". my packet is bigger than one.in my IP payload, I have two sections : header and body, So I have to implement such as seq_number myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "my packet is bigger than one"? Did you meant to say that theres packet fragmentation? TCP is always in the trasport layer. seq_number is in the header of the tcp segment - as you can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure . its part of the tcp protocol.

Comment: My program generates some text, and `recv*`  functions family is limited to its buffer.